# Response Message: Non HTTP response message: No PrivateKey found for alias:'qa_hialcdr-publall-cons_di-cons_master_ppe'

Tags: performance, jmeter, automated-tests

I have an API. I need to run test using JMeter. But when I run it before it's passed but now I am getting below error. I am not sure this error is because of unsupported java format or environment unavailability

> **Error**:-
> ?Data type("text"|"bin"|""):text
> Response code: Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException
> Response message: Non HTTP response message: No PrivateKey found for alias:'qa_hialcdr-publall-cons_di-cons_master_ppe'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First, check if your keystore contains a certificate with alias a_hialcdr-publall-cons_di-cons_master_ppe (assuming this is the correct name of the certificate that you want to use).

```
keytool -list -keystore path/to/your/keystore -alias a_hialcdr-publall-cons_di-cons_master_ppe
```

Then, check if the keystore is properly set up in system.properties file in jmeter "bin" folder. You should see something like this:

```
javax.net.ssl.keyStore=path/to/your/keystore
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit
```

If the above are both ok, the issue could be that you are using a JKS keystore, but the certificate with alias a_hialcdr-publall-cons_di-cons_master_ppe was imported from a PKCS12 file. For some reason, JMeter can't read such certificates from within a JKS keystore. The solution is to create a PKCS12 keystore and point JMeter to it.

If you have individual PKCS12 files, [merge them into a single PKCS12 keystore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48225720/merge-p12-files-into-single-keystore). Make sure all certs in the keystore have the same password. Alternatively, you can [convert the JKS to PKCS12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846828/converting-jks-to-p12).

Then, in your system.properties file, point the SSL properties to your new file.

```
javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12
javax.net.ssl.keyStore=path/to/your/keystore.p12
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit
```

Then re-run your tests. This was the solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using [Keystore Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Keystore_Configuration) and [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) in order to pass [multiple client-side certificates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-multiple-certificates-when-load-testing-secure-websites) along with your HTTP Requests.

The error means that:

1. The CSV file contains entry with the name of `qa_hialcdr-publall-cons_di-cons_master_ppe`
2. And the [keystore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_KeyStore) containing your client-side certificates doesn't contain an entry with such an alias

So ensure that all entries in the CSV files have matching certificates in the keystore and that should be it.